# How to serialize to this specific JSON format

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, mailgun

I've a list of recipients as a list. How can I serialize the c# objects to this specific JSON format requested by mailgun?

**C#**

```
var recipients = new List<Recipient>
    {
        new Recipient("test1@foo.com", "Foo Bar 1", "1234"),
        new Recipient("test2@foo.com", "Foo Bar 2", "9876"),
        ...
    }
```

**Expected JSON** (According to https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#batch-sending)

```
{
   "test1@foo.com": { "name": "Foo Bar 1", "customerNumber": "1234" },
   "test2@foo.com": { "name": "Foo Bar 2", "customerNumber": "9876" },
}
```

Using `JsonObject` and the serializable method `SimgpleJson.SerializeObject()` will produces JSON like this:

```
{
    [
        {"test1@foo.com": { "name": "Foo Bar 1", "customerNumber": "1234" }},
        {"test2@foo.com": { "name": "Foo Bar 2", "customerNumber": "9876" }},
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code? (In cases like that I just use LINQ to JSON from JSON.NET: easier to get a specific format than using serialisation).

Comment: You have an array instead of multiple single objects. This can be changed by serializing the string, removing the [ and ] and deserializing again. there will very likely be a better solution without serializing tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use following class to serialize the object

```
 public class Test1FooCom
   {
      public string name { get; set; }
      public string customerNumber { get; set; }
   }


var obj = new Dictionary<string, Test1FooCom>
   {
    {"test1@foo.com", new Test1FooCom(){name="Foo Bar 1",customerNumber="1234"}},
    {"test2@foo.com", new Test1FooCom(){name="Foo Bar 2",customerNumber="9876"}},        
   };

   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

**Output Json**

```
    {  
    "test1@foo.com":{  
        "name":"Foo Bar 1",
        "customerNumber":"1234"
    },
    "test2@foo.com":{  
        "name":"Foo Bar 2",
        "customerNumber":"9876"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use Dictionary for expected JSON, like this :

```
var recipients = new Dictionary<string, Recipient>
    {
        {"test1@foo.com", new Recipient("Foo Bar 1", "1234")},
        {"test2@foo.com", new Recipient("Foo Bar 2", "9876")},
        ...
    }
```

or this one :

```
var recipients = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                {"test1@foo.com", new  {name = "Foo Bar 1", customerNumber = "1234"}},
                {"test2@foo.com", new  {name = "Foo Bar 2", customerNumber = "9876"}}
            };

            Debug.WriteLine(recipients.ToJson());
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual result is correct. 
A list of recipients immediately translated to an array construct [], so anything inside this list will show as you have on your actual output.

Your expectation would not work, as it would deserialize back into ths:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Test1FooCom test1foocom { get; set; }
    public Test2FooCom test2foocom { get; set; }
}

public class Test1FooCom
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string customerNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Test2FooCom
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string customerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're right, but I think mailgun (as he mentions) requires the other format